# lumen route error handleDispatcherResponse(array('0'))

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, lumen

Below is my route in lumen.

```
$app->get('contact-us/{msg?}', function (){
    echo Input::all();
});
```

It throws the following error.

```
at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array('0')) in Application.php line 1184
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\{closure}() in Application.php line 1414
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure)) in Application.php line 1185
at Application->dispatch(object(Request)) in Application.php line 1125
at Application->run(object(Request)) in index.php line 31
```

I want to pass the optional parameter **`msg`** to controller. How to pass it?

Comment: the parameter you want to send to the controller?

Answer (score 1):

In public/index.php do the following edit:

```
//$app->run();
$app->run($app->make('request'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the **rewrite rules** of your `Apache` or `Nginx` sever aren't correctly set, so Lumen cannot parse the URL in the right way.
If you're using `Nginx`, please use this config:

```
index  index.html index.htm index.php;
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php;
}   
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
```

And routes should start with `/` :

```
$app->get('/contact-us/{msg?}', function () {
    echo Input::all();
});
```

If these solutions didn't work, try debugging with **RoutesRequests.php**, adding some debug outputs will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

To send the data to the controller do the following

```
$app->get('contact-us/{msg?}', 'YourController@mehtod');
```

And in your controller you will receive data as well

```
public function method($message)
{

}
```